# how to get the index of facts in RHS of rule?

Tags: clips

I'm asking if there is a possibility of accessing a get the index of fact in RHS of defrule ?
It gives me that undefined every time I try to index a fact in a RHS of defrule.
because I have a while loop , I want to be able to modify elevator fact depending on my input data.

```
(deftemplate elevator 
(slot goal))

(deffacts elevator
(elevator (goal 0))) 

(defrule read-data

=>
?f1 <- (elevator)
(modify ?f2 (goal 1))

)
```

this an example of my code , since I can't put all online :

```
(deftemplate data
(slot data)
)

(deffacts data
(data (data 1))
)

(defrule rule1
?f1 <-(data)
=>
(bind ?value (readline input) )
(while (neq ?value EOF) 
do
(bind ?data (fact-slot-value ?f1 data)) 
(printout t "data " ?data crlf )
(retract ?f1)
(modify ?f1 (data ?value))
(bind ?value (readline input) 
)

)
)
```

this is my input file :

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

this is what I'm getting :

```
CLIPS> (run)
data 1
data FALSE
data FALSE
data FALSE
data FALSE
data FALSE
CLIPS>
```

I want it to print out 
data 2 
data 3
data 4  ..ect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way from the RHS of a rule, but if your rule actually has no LHS conditions, it's pointless to use a rule to change the value of the fact. Just use a function.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate elevator 
   (slot goal))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts elevator
   (elevator (goal 0))) 
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-data
   =>
   (do-for-fact ((?f elevator)) TRUE
      (modify ?f (goal 1))))
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (reset)
<== f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-1     (elevator (goal 0))
CLIPS> (run)
<== f-1     (elevator (goal 0))
==> f-2     (elevator (goal 1))
CLIPS>
```

Alternately, you can bind the fact you want to modify in the conditions of the rule:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate elevator 
   (slot goal))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts elevator
   (elevator (goal 0))) 
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-data
   ?f <- (elevator (goal 0))
   =>
   (modify ?f (goal 1)))
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (reset)
<== f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-1     (elevator (goal 0))
CLIPS> (run)
<== f-1     (elevator (goal 0))
==> f-2     (elevator (goal 1))
CLIPS>
```

Updated:

You can get your original rule to "work" by removing the retract and rebinding ?f1 to the value returned by modify:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate data
   (slot data))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts data
   (data (data 1)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule1
   ?f1 <- (data)
   =>
   (bind ?value (readline input))
   (while (neq ?value EOF) 
      (bind ?data (fact-slot-value ?f1 data)) 
      (printout t "data " ?data crlf )
      (bind ?f1 (modify ?f1 (data ?value)))
      (bind ?value (readline input))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (open input.txt input)
TRUE
CLIPS> (run)
data 1
data 2
data 3
data 4
data 5
data 6
CLIPS> (close input)
TRUE
CLIPS>
```

It's still suspiciously complicated to be modifying the same fact multiple times on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks , but I'm asking what if I'm in a loop ..right now I am writing code in which it is a while loop that goes through input file , and depending on that input file the fact elevator changing depending on goal. It works well for the first iteration only , but its not changing for the rest of iterations